# When should we use the word 'status quo'?

Tags: word-usage

I know 'status quo' means the existing state of affairs, especially regarding social or political issues.

When should we use the word 'status quo'?

(Here is a [related ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63428/can-status-quo-be-used-in-regards-to-micro-topics).)

Comment: What isn't clear from the definition and the answers to the previous question?

Comment: @Edwin: This question belongs on ELL, but the linked question and answers mangle it horribly.  In that scenario, change is certainly afoot (of marital status, not name), and therefore to say the status quo is maintained seems very wrong.

Comment: I don't understand what the question here is. You use *status quo* whenever that is the term that expresses what you want to express. Just like with any other word. When should we use the word *car*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the term status quo when the following are met:

- there is a defined state to compare that has been (very) stable
- that everyone accepts that this defined state is stable and is somewhat considered the same by most/all people
- that your audience understands what status quo means.